# Yii2 - how to force response JSON formatter to use objects instead of arrays?

Tags: php, json, yii, yii2, httpresponse

I know I can set `Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON` but how I can make it set the JSON encoding flag `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` so that all arrays will be encoded as objects instead?

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-jsonresponseformatter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, it wasn't so hard:

```php
Yii::$app->response->formatters[\yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON] = [
    'class' => 'yii\web\JsonResponseFormatter',
    'encodeOptions' => JSON_FORCE_OBJECT,
];
```

Or even as a one-liner:

```
Yii::$app->response->formatters[\yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON]['encodeOptions'] = JSON_FORCE_OBJECT;
```